# Update sales order items using a workflow in NetSuite

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

I'm starting to get the hang of NetSuite but this one has stumped me. I am looking for a way to update the line items on an order from a workflow in NetSuite.  From what I can tell it doesn't seem to expose those fields, is there any way around this?

I have a saved search returning all of the transaction line items that I want modified, there is a field on the Sales Order Line Item called "Create Fulfillment Order".  It shows up under saved searches as "Create Fulfillment Order Column", but when I add an action to a workflow to set the field value, the only fields that show up are Sales Order fields.  Is there any way to access the Sales Order Column fields, since that's really what's being returned by my saved search anyways.

I've looked at the Sub Types defined in the workflow to see if there's one for Sales Order Item or anything but there's not, just Sales Order.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that will let you access transaction line items from a workflow.  You'll need to use SuiteScript to create a custom workflow action.  Then you can call that action from your workflow.

Comment: This is true. The things that you can only do on workflow for transaction is to transform it into different type. Lets say SO to IR or SO to Invoice. You can also edit the header of the transaction but not the lines. Lastly, you can't create new record if the transaction requires item lines.

Comment: Thanks I was afraid that there wasn't a way to do it from just the workflow, I'll look at the custom workflow action using SuiteScript, thank you for the help.